# Colorspace of image loaded from gallery using Picasso or Glide in android?

Tags: android, image-processing, picasso, android-glide, color-space

I have loaded an image into image view using Glide library. I want to know in which colorspace this image is. Also what will be the colorspace of image captured using intent(native camera).

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/q/21779371/8089770

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I need to detect colorspace(RGB,BGR .etc.) of image not color of pixel